# Remove event listener when using jQuery proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery `proxy()` to enable scope inside a handler when using `addEventListener`:

```
document.addEventListener('onSomeEvent', $.proxy(myHandler, this));
```

Now, normally when I want to remove event I used to call:

```
document.removeEventListener('onSomeEvent', myHandler, false);
```

How can I do that when using the `$.proxy()` option in jQuery?

Comment: You would have to keep track of the proxied function in a variable. Since you're using jQuery, may I ask why you do not take advantage of its event handling system instead of calling `addEventListener()` (not supported in older versions of Internet Explorer)?

Comment: @Xenon, nope, `$.proxy()` will return a new proxied function for each call.

Comment: @Xenon, like Frederic said... this is the problem...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Till now I know I can use jquery event (bind and trigger) on a DOM object... Can I use the jquery events for objects I created? objects with constructor and prototype..

Comment: What do you mean by `objects with constructor and prototype`? The event system is tied to the DOM (both with jQuery and `addEventListener()`). I don't think you can use it with non-DOM objects. You can still implement a callback system yourself, though (or use jQuery's callbacks facility).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I mean when i'm creating my own events with `document.createEvent()`

Comment: Ah, indeed jQuery's `trigger()` and `on()` have no problem handling custom events. You won't lose features in that area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myHandlerProxied = $.proxy(myHandler, this);
document.addEventListener('onSomeEvent', myHandlerProxied);

document.removeEventListener('onSomeEvent', myHandlerProxied, false);
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't thought about this! feels so stupid /:Thanks @wong2

Comment: Why not .on("someevent",myHandlerProxied) ?